# What is the white powder on sourdough bread?

Tags: baking, sourdough

I often see sourdough bread loaves with a white powder/dust on the crust.

What is this white powder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically that would be whatever was used for dusting the loaves or the bannetons, either flour, starch or sometimes [semolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semolina).

It is done to prevent sticking and for decorative purposes - often both:

[image]
([Source](https://www.weekendbakery.com/posts/video-how-to-break-in-a-new-banneton/))

Comment: I believe rice flour specifically is quite popular for dusting the bannetons.